# Does Improved Catalyst increase self-damage from Rigged Bombs?

Tags: peglin

The description for Improved Catalyst says that Bombs and Rigged Bombs will deal +10 damage. Normally Rigged Bombs deal 150 damage to enemies and 3 self damage to the player.

Does Improved Catalyst increase the amount of self-damage taken when activating Rigged Bombs?

[image: Improved Catalyst]

Comment: Bomb damage and self damage are always mentioned separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Improved Catalyst only increases damage dealt to enemies. Rigged Bombs still only did 3 self damage after I picked it up